# Small JavaScript function that mimics flag handling of the command line

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that I would use to handle parameters with options for use later in another project.

A sample input would be similar to this:

```
foo bar --baz con str --w=1920 --h=1080
```

From the example above I would expect `foo` and `bar` to be not part of any flag and `baz` would contain `con` and `str` and `w` with the value of `1920` and `h` with `1080`:

```
foo
bar
baz = [con, str]
w   = 1920
h   = 1080
```

This `getFlags` function would take a string and perform the "flag" logic that I had in mind.

```javascript
const getFlags = (str) => {
  const prefix = '--';

  const strArray = str
    .trim()
    .replaceAll(/\s+/ig, ' ')
    .split(' ');

  let flagArray = {
    _noFlag: {
      values: [],
    },
  };

  let lastArg = '';
  strArray.forEach((arg) => {
    if (arg.startsWith(prefix) && arg.length > prefix.length) {
      noPrefixFlag = arg.slice(prefix.length);

      if (noPrefixFlag.includes('=')) {
        const pair = noPrefixFlag.split('=');
        flagArray[pair[0]] = {
          values: [pair[1]],
        };
        lastArg = '';
      } else {
        lastArg = noPrefixFlag;
        flagArray[lastArg] = {
          values: [],
        };
      }

    } else if (lastArg) {
      flagArray[lastArg].values.push(arg);
    } else {
      flagArray._noFlag.values.push(arg);
    }
  });

  return flagArray;
};
```

It works as I expect it, but I feel like this function can be improved.